# Tensorflow concat/split issue in recurrent network example

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Consider the following example code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import math
import numpy as np

INPUTS = 10
HIDDEN_1 = 20
BATCH_SIZE = 3


def iterate_state(prev_state_tuple, input):
    with tf.name_scope('h1'):
        weights = tf.get_variable('W', shape=[INPUTS, HIDDEN_1], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(INPUTS))))
        biases = tf.get_variable('bias', shape=[HIDDEN_1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        matmuladd = tf.matmul(inputs, weights) + biases
        print("prev state: ",prev_state_tuple.get_shape())
        unpacked_state, unpacked_out = tf.split(0,2,prev_state_tuple)
        prev_state = unpacked_state
        state = 0.9* prev_state + 0.1*matmuladd
        output = tf.nn.relu(state)
        print(" state: ", state.get_shape())
        print(" output: ", output.get_shape())
        concat_result = tf.concat(0,[state, output])
        print (" concat return: ", concat_result.get_shape())
        return concat_result

def data_iter():
    while True:
        idxs = np.random.rand(BATCH_SIZE, INPUTS)
        yield idxs

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(BATCH_SIZE, INPUTS))
    with tf.variable_scope('states'):
        initial_state = tf.zeros([HIDDEN_1],
                                 name='initial_state')
        initial_out = tf.zeros([HIDDEN_1],
                                 name='initial_out')
        concat_tensor = tf.concat(0,[initial_state, initial_out])
        print(" init state: ",initial_state.get_shape())
        print(" init out: ",initial_out.get_shape())
        print(" concat: ",concat_tensor.get_shape())
        scanout = tf.scan(iterate_state, inputs, initializer=concat_tensor, name='state_scan')
        print ("scanout shape: ", scanout.get_shape())
        state, output = tf.split(0,2,scanout, name='split_scan_output')

    sess = tf.Session()
    # Run the Op to initialize the variables.
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    iter_ = data_iter()
    for i in xrange(0, 2):
        print ("iteration: ",i)
        input_data = iter_.next()
        out,st = sess.run([output,state], feed_dict={ inputs: input_data})
```

I am trying to concatenate and split the internal state and output tensors together so that it can conform to the `tf.scan` interface.

However, when running this example, I get this error:

```
(' init state: ', TensorShape([Dimension(20)]))
(' init out: ', TensorShape([Dimension(20)]))
(' concat: ', TensorShape([Dimension(40)]))
('prev state: ', TensorShape([Dimension(40)]))
(' state: ', TensorShape([Dimension(3), Dimension(20)]))
(' output: ', TensorShape([Dimension(3), Dimension(20)]))
(' concat return: ', TensorShape([Dimension(6), Dimension(20)]))
('scanout shape: ', TensorShape(None))
('iteration: ', 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cycles_in_graphs_with_scan.py", line 57, in <module>
    out,st = sess.run([output,state], feed_dict={ inputs: input_data})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 340, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 564, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 637, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 659, in _do_call
    e.code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Number of ways to split should evenly divide the split dimension, but got split_dim 0 (size = 3) and num_split 2
     [[Node: states/split_scan_output = Split[T=DT_FLOAT, num_split=2, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](states/split_scan_output/split_dim, states/state_scan/TensorArrayPack)]]
Caused by op u'states/split_scan_output', defined at:
  File "cycles_in_graphs_with_scan.py", line 46, in <module>
    state, output = tf.split(0,2,scanout, name='split_scan_output')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 525, in split
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1428, in _split
    num_split=num_split, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 655, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2154, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1154, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

while the return tensor has clearly dimensions `(6,20)` as shown, the return from `tf.scan` seems to have a shape of `None`, while the error says that it is finding an object of length 3

Any idea what might be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `tf.scan()` function is unable to infer a static shape for the output, and thus you're getting a runtime failure when you try to split `scanout` into 2 tensors on the 0th dimension.

In cases like this, the best thing to do is to evaluate `scanout` to see what its actual shape is:

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
iter_ = data_iter()
input_data = iter_.next()
scanout_val = sess.run(scanout, feed_dict={inputs: input_data})

print("Actual shape of scanout:", scanout_val.shape)
```

From the error message it looks like it has size 3 in the 0th dimension, which I suspect comes from the batch size, because the 0th dimension of `tf.scan()`'s input and output will have the same size. One possibility is that you actually want to split on the 1st dimension:

```
state, output = tf.split(1, 2, scanout, name='split_scan_output')
```

Comment: I tried switching the concat and split dimension from 0 to 1, but I get exactly the same error

Comment: What's the actual shape of the data when you run it? (You probably only need to switch the split dimension, and can leave the concat dimension alone.... Running your code with `tf.split(1, ...)` works for me.)

Comment: the errors in my post show the prints with the printed shapes

Comment: if I put an 1-index dimension in the `split` I get no errors, but the resulting tensors `state` and `output` have also `TensorShape(None)`

Comment: That's okay though—it just means that the shapes can't be inferred statically. Your program should still work.

Comment: ok, after the out and state nodes are run in the session, both output and state tensors are shaped `(3,3,20)`. I have no idea why. I was expecting them to be shaped `(BATCH_SIZE, HIDDEN_1)` instead

Comment: the `scanout_val` object is shaped `(3,6,20)`, which explains the error with 0th dimension, but I have no idea why I'm getting this shape

Comment: The shape of `tf.scan()` is given in [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/functional_ops.html#scan): "The shape of the result tensor is `[len(values)] + fn(initializer, values[0]).shape`." `len(values)` is 3, so `iterate_values()` must return a tensor of shape `(6, 20)`. It's likely that `tf.scan()` is iterating over the wrong dimension - the batch dimension - instead of a time dimension. I can't tell from your data which dimension is the time dimension, however. If it isn't the 0th dimension, you might need to `tf.transpose()` the input to use `tf.scan()`.

Comment: my data is just random test data with shape `(3,10)`, define at `data_iter()`

Comment: OK, if you want to scan over the dimension of length 10, rather than the batch dimension, you'll need to `tf.transpose(inputs)` before passing it to `tf.scan()`.

Comment: so, when the docs say `[len(values)] + fn(initializer, values[0]).shape`, I didn't realise that + is python list concatenation. So the fn and scan should be iterating over the batch dimension, calling `fn` once for each batch element, so the time dimension (over which the internal state evolves) and the batch dimension are actually the same

Comment: That's right. In many RNN examples in TensorFlow, the batch dimension and time dimension will be different (i.e. you will have a batch of sequences, e.g. sentences or other sequential data). If you are intending to iterate over the batch dimension, then the code you have should work.